# CakePHP - file structure confusion - different controllers, or all in same?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

To understand my confusion/question, let me first give a quick overview of the site I'm building:   The site has a homepage, and 7 category pages, each with the same/similar layout.

On most category homepages (eg "Dining"), you can do a search (ie a search for restaurants), which will take you to a results page.  This will have the same/similar layout as the... "Theaters" search result page...etc etc.

So - although there are a lot of sections, there are not a lot of page layouts.

**Question:  I'm not sure if I should create separate controllers for each, and just use the same CSS for them?  Or if I can use the same view file, but populate each content area on the page differently based on the url/action..etc?**

They'll all reference different & multiple tables in the database - for instance, restaurants will reference the restaurants table, the cuisines table, the zip_codes table...etc.  Theaters might reference the "movies" table, the zip_codes table...etc etc etc

But - I also want an admin tool for some - ie "restaurants/edit" or "theaters/edit" ...etc - not ALL the pages will have admin for that specific url - ie "outdoors" might just be "businesses/edit" or something generic... I don't know - I'm confused as you can tell.

**Any help is GREATLY appreciated.**  I've read a lot about the technical things to do w/ CakePHP, but I can't find any good resources for general project structures for varying scenarios.

Comment: Definitely only 1 category controller. You can simply use a different view if the view is very different for each category.

Comment: This differs from other answers can you explain?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you were planning on having separate controllers for similar categories. The answers given below are sound, group them and refactor. You might want to `bake` your code and then take it from there so you don't have too much base work to layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can answer this yourself. Suppose you implement separate controllers, models and views for each, how do they differ? If they only differ in the table names and labels/strings that they use, then you can use just one generic controller. But, if they are different in other ways (e.g. the Restaurants model has a totally different relationship structure than a Movie model) then use separate controllers.

To prevent too many repetition between controllers and view files when you do use separate controllers, try to push functionality in a common base controller (e.g. AppController, of create your own base controller based on AppController that your MoviesController and RestaurantsController and so on will derive from). Push generic view code into elements.

A word about CSS: Of course you can (and should) reuse that. It's mostyly separate from the view. Just use sensible class names and id's in your views and the CSS will be easy to reuse.

If you are still unsure, I'd go with separate controllers. It may be more work but it will be cleaner and easier to debug. Use the above suggestions to avoid repetition.

Comment: Thank all for the help - I suppose my question was too general, but this one did the best at attempting to answer it.  It also clued me in to "elements", which I'd previously not used/read about.

Answer (score 0):

-group elements that will share among all site in a layout (ie. site css, site common js library)
-make a view for each of your category(page)  (ie. dining page, theater page, restaurants page) and put there page only stuff (ie. theater js, theater includes) there
- in theory, every vew should have a controller and model, so you have to make them separate.

anyway url like  "restaurants/edit" or "theaters/edit" actually means model "restaurant", operation "edit" in your controller file.

I suggest you read the [blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog) from cakephp site, you that should answer all your confusion

Comment: I understand that "restaurants/edit" is the edit function in my restaurants controller - that's beside the point though - my question is, should I make all my pages in separate controllers, or keep them all in "pages/restaurants" for example

Comment: you should make them separate. because a restaurant controller should only do restaurant stuffs, and theater controller does theater stuff

Comment: but like @Sander Marechal said, you may try to do them in separate controllers, then see if you can refactor some similar operation into a "generic" controller appController

Comment: I appreciate the advice - I'll likely go separate for now, and combine once I get better at it :)