# Cake php architecture

Tags: cakephp, architecture, components

I've a question for CakePHP about its architecture.

I've an application, which will have only two models(products and categories).

I've to make an online product browser. For me it makes no sens to have one controller "Products" and one controller "Categories", because I will have 20+ actions on the Products and none on the Categories.

I've several key functionnalities, can I have one controller for each of those functionnalities? e.g. One Controller "Search", which have action "SearchResult", "AdvancedSearch", "BasicSearch".

We will be several developers on this project and I don't wish we are always all blocked because one is doing some edit on the product controller(and I really don't like file with 1000+ lines of code).

Second question: What is the mecanism I should use to fragment view in several different sub-view?
E.g. For the view of the details of one product, I've a lot of things to display: Pictures section, description section, similar products, review, ... Is it possible to have sub-part?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For "sub-views" look into Elements, which are just that. They are snippets of view code that can be included in other views.  The proper structuring of elements can create some very elegant view/subview relationships.
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements

As for your controller issue, it's one I've grappled with as well. From what I see, it sounds like you're misclassifying your actions. Think about alternative taxonomies for the actions you're doing (mixing all the search functions together into a controller is a great example).

Perhaps you should think about controllers as objects that classify various actions rather than aspects of your site on which various actions can be performed (as it seems you're doing).  So rather than a CATEGORY controller on which you can search, list, buy, etc., you might have, the product controller (which handles viewing your products either in an aggregate - perhaps by category -  or individually), and perhaps a user controller for your users accounts? It's hard to say without looking at your application specifics. Search would then be an **action** that would be performed on your **product**.

One thing that I have made the mistake of doing is picking my controllers based on **pages** i'll have rather than on **models**. Think about your data (models) and the actions that can be performed on them (actions in the controller), THEN think about your views.

I wish I could give you more specific help, but without knowing your application's specific needs, I can only give you guidelines on how to break down your controllers. Take a look at this question:

[CakePHP - file structure confusion - different controllers, or all in same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476598/cakephp-file-structure-confusion-different-controllers-or-all-in-same)

for more discussion on the topic.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Okay, great for the "elements". 

The problem is that on this app, I only have to display/search/view details/view related products/... actions on the "product" model, the thing is that it will makes an huge file with the 80% of my code, and I can't think it's a good idea.

Comment: One more thing, I've three table which contains the same information but in different language, how can I do only one controller and switch only the table depending the language?

Comment: This should be a different SO question so that everyone can benefit, but my thought would be to either create one model that switches it's underlying table based on routing logic (check prefixes and $useTable properties) or - if each table is complex or different enough to have different data at some points look into swapping models in the controller using the $uses property. There's a lot to that question though...

Comment: as for the "elements" discussion, if your app truly is simply for the viewing of products/comparison thereof, then perhaps everything does indeed belong in one controller. I know the instinct of modularity makes you feel like that's a mistake, but sometimes there's nothing more fundamental to break your representation down to..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Categories controller if you have no methods/actions associated with it. I assume you may want an admin CRUD for administrating your categories?

Regarding searching; your core search functions should reside in the Products model with the various controllers calling the appropriate methods. Basic or Advanced searching on one model in most cases can be handled by one method, its only a matter of more search fields surely?

If you have several developers and are worried about conflicts on the same file you really need to be considering version control like [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) or [SVN](http://subversion.apache.org/) rather than approaches contrary to a MVC frameworks core methodology. It will cause you a lot less problems in the future.

I believe you question regarding 'sub views' is solved by using [elements](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements), which is in effect reusable sections of views.

good luck

Comment: I know that I doesn't need a category controller, and no I don't want any admin section, we are connected on a view of an ERP.

Comment: The search function is really really more complex and smart than just search the input in all fields, we have to interprate the input(e.g. if we see a 150ml, we have to convert it to 0.150 and search it into the volume column, and we have >, <, <=, >= operators, e.g. for wine <2000 has to return only wine older than eleven years(dummy example), and all these criteria can be cumulate.
We already have a code version control(TFS).

But it doesn't really tell me if I have to had ALL the logic of my entire website in one file, which will makes an huge file, where we cannot find anything easily

Comment: And source control help merging files, it doesn't avoid that someone has to change the functionality of one method, and one other too, and they change the two the same method...